# Output from PHP MD5 and Solaris Digest MD5 dont match

Tags: php, unix

When i run the below code in PHP

```
$saltedPW =  "Test12309566173258152148992";
$hashedPW = md5($saltedPW);
echo $hashedPW;
```

the output i get is fc8f7b8737b9d4754ff1156a3ad88b03

when i run the above in bash shell on a solaris box

```
echo Test12309566173258152148992 | digest -a md5
```

the output i get is 04df7b4ce498b87d696b32140ca63f6a

am I doing something wrong guys ?

i have tried double quotes in shell and I still get the same result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because `echo` appends a newline by default, you need to add `-n` argument:

```
echo -n Test12309566173258152148992 | digest -a md5
# fc8f7b8737b9d4754ff1156a3ad88b03
```